# Excel formula to identify gaps in overlapping date ranges

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that will allow me to easily see if there are any gaps in dates across two different date ranges.

In this example, I need to check that the dates given in Columns C and D (their contract dates) cover the time period given in columns A to B (the actual dates worked)

[image]

I have seen there is a 'gap' formula but that only seems to work if I have two columns of dates, not two different date ranges going across 4 columns

Comment: `cover the time period given in columns A to D (the actual dates worked)` shouldn't the "actual dates worked" be columns A and B?

Comment: Pls. try this formula `=IF(B2<A2,"Actual error",IF(OR(C2>A2,D2<B2),"Not in","OK"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula

`=IF((A2:A5>=C2:C5)*(B2:B5<=D2:D5),"OK", "Not OK")`

It spills to all four rows.

Using `*` is like and `AND`.

[image]